# Using 2 same values in 1 row -> SQL 2008 table

Tags: sql-server

I've searched for this thingy a lot.. and I can not find a solution since I'm beginner in SQL itself.

I used to edit games database. now, I need to create a new table with 1 row called "CodeName128" and it should contain the same value many times..
when I place something like

```
CODE_NAME1
CODE_NAME1
```

it tells me No rows was updated blabla which means this table already have this code.

how can I get over it and enable the duplication in table?

Live example:
[image]

Comment: remove the unique key from that column.

Comment: You have a primary key constraint on the column. A primary key enforces uniqueness on values.

Comment: Use a unique key instead of one already in the db so SQL server can see it's a new row

Comment: Thanks guys. worked :3

Answer (score 1):

You must be having Primary key or Unique key defined on that column which is not allowing you to enter the duplicate values. The keys must be defined for a reason, so its not advisable to remove those, still if you think that duplicate values are required for that column, you have to alter the table structure and remove those constraints from that column.